# Get a "date" type from the DB and add seconds

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine

```
public function updateAuction($id)
{   
    $AuctionsTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('auctions');

    $auction = $AuctionsTable->find($id);

    $auction->ends_at += 10; 

    $auction->save();
}
```

I'm using Doctrine to get a record from the database.

I need to increase number of seconds on this records ends_at column, which is a date type.

`+=` of course didn't work. What is the quickest way to add, let's say, 10 seconds to ends_at variable? And having handled all the other nuisances that might appear (59 + 10 = 69 seconds).

Perhaps I should use mysql's `addtime()` function? But is that implemented with Doctrine? Didn't find anything about `addtime()` on doctrine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert the value from the DB into a [DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) in PHP
2. Use the [DateTime::add function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) to add the seconds
3. Put the resulting value back into the DB

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you very much! ;) By the way, had a little trouble, because I had to use $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); aswell, to get the stringed version, then I could assign the stringed value to $auction->ends_at.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sec = new Zend_Date($auction->ends_at, Zend_Date::SECOND);
$auction->ends_at = $sec->addSecond(10);
$auction->save();
```

Comment: I get a "no element found" in firebug when i add the Zend_Date line.

Comment: Hm, but I'm not using the zend framework. I'm using Symfony. Don't have that class.

Comment: ah! sorry! :S then follow the advice of normalocity! ;)